# How can I find next run times of Azure Scheduler Collection Job

Tags: azure, azure-scheduler

I have azure scheduler job created with the below parameters.

```
"properties": {
   "startTime": "2019-03-31T00:00Z", 
   "recurrence": {
      "frequency": "Months",
      "interval": 1,         
      "end": "Never"
   },
}
```

This is intended to run once in a month every starting on 31/3/2019 9:00 PM.

Now I would like to get next 10 execution times of this job. Is there a way to get this? May be using Powershell?

This is required for me to understand, when the job runs as there is no 31/4/2019, it's only 30 days in April.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, your scheduler job will start at 019-03-31T00:00Z and will run every month. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-advanced-complexity.

Comment: Yes. But, do you know how to get the list of next 10 schedule times?